# How to select option to change value select option by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have 2 `<select>` inputs. If I select an option in the first input, I want to filter the options by id based on the selected option of the first input.

I have defined id for each options in the second input (`"prod"+id`)

This is HTML:

```
<select id="provider" name="provider">
    <option selected="selected" value="">--- Select providers ---</option>
    <option value="1">Provider 1</option>
    <option value="2">Provider 2</option>
    <option value="3">Provider 3</option>
</select>

<select id="product" name="product">
    <option id="" value="" selected="selected">--- Select products ---</option> 
    <option id="prod2" value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option id="prod2" value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option id="prod2" value="3">Product 3</option>
    <option id="prod3" value="4">Product 4</option>
    <option id="prod1" value="5">Product 5</option>
    <option>
</select>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#provider').change(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val();
        $('#type').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == filter) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            $('#prod1').val(filter);
        })
    })
})
```

I want to show products from the selected provider only.

Online Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/notfoundlife/BCedV/1/

Comment: So whats the question here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are not selecting the individual options, but the whole select list, so everything is hiding. Try changing the selector like this and go from there.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#provider').change(function(){
   var filter = $(this).val();
   $('#type option').each(function(){
           if ($(this).val() == filter) {
             $(this).show();
           } else {
             $(this).hide();
           }
     })
  })
})
```

Comment: if ($(this).attr('id') == filter) { i am get value of id option. this id is id of provider, it working correct. Thankyou Bingo. http://jsfiddle.net/notfoundlife/BCedV/28/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html above, I think this should work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#provider').change(function(){
   var filter = $(this).val();
   $('#product option[value=' + filter +']').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
```